# Complex SQL Exclude Logic with set based operations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'd prefer to use set logic rather than iterating over the table with a cursor or something, but if that's what is needed it can be done.

I am basically preparing a view in a stored procedure that will be used elsewhere for BI. Right now the stored procedure is just a select statement pulling from various tables with a decent amount of joins and other random logic.

Here is an example of about what the tables would look like. First, the table that will be returned, second what exclusions the user wants to make. 
[image: Example]

I want to look at each record in the excludes table and then apply that as a filter to the first table, so it would eliminate all the rows where the items match. (It will get a bit more complex down the road because they could select to eliminate an entire LocationCode, which would then cascade through all the WarehouseCodes and everything below it. It's basically a hierarchy. But I want to get the general idea down).

I wasn't sure how to do it with a NOT EXISTS since I have to go row by row. I'm not sure if i have to use a cursor or iterate over another way. I'm wondering if there is another tool in SQL I am not aware of.

Any suggestions on how to efficiently eliminate rows based on another tables values would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get whole rows from Table1 except rows which have similars in Table2, you can do this:

```
select * -- Column list here
from Table1 as t
where
    not exists (
        select t.LocationCode, t.WarehouseCode, t.WarehouseName, t.StorageAddress
        intersect
        select t2.LocationCode, t2.WarehouseCode, t2.WarehouseName, t2.StorageAddress
        from Table2 as t2
    )
```

or more convinient

```
select * -- Column list here
from Table1 as t
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from Table2 as t2
        where
            t2.LocationCode = t.LocationCode and
            t2.WarehouseCode = t.WarehouseCode and
            t2.WarehouseName = t.WarehouseName and
            t2.StorageAddress = t.StorageAddress
    )
```

Comment: I was able to use the second query, and then have the following statement in the WHERE clause to conditionally limit ( AND (t2.WarehouseCode = 'ALL' OR t2.WarehouseCode = t1.WarehouseCode) ).

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [`EXCEPT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clause, which works similarly to a `UNION`

```
select col1, col2, col3 from yourtable
EXCEPT
select col1, col2, col3 from exceptions
```

Comment: I'm not sure I want it to return distinct values, and having to match up the rows in the query might take a few extra steps to set up overall

Answer (score 0):

there are two things to solve here. in the first case you have explain the Exclude table has same number of columns as in actual table. i am assuming here that some columns in this tables will be 
“NULL able” and some might not be. so during exclusion you need to take care of that as well. I see "Left Join" is a good candidate to use here because of the performance reasons and also you can perform MATCHING on selected columns only if needed. In your case right now it seems like all columns needed to match but think about in future if Identity/datetime/timestamp like column added on the table.
see the below code. if the data in this tables are high in volume proper NON-Clustered and/or Filter Index will help you to improve the perfrmance but that is at later stage if you see the view queries are slow.

For the second part where you mentioned, later you might decide to exclude a Location Code completely and there are Hierarchical dependency. 
I would say keep this separate until you have exact requirement.

```
    DECLARE @AllData TABLE
    (
        ID      INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,FName  sysname     NOT NULL
        ,LName  sysname     NOT NULL
        ,MName  sysname     NULL
    )

    DECLARE @ExcludeData TABLE
    (
        ID      INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        ,FName  sysname     NOT NULL
        ,LName  sysname     NOT NULL
        ,MName  sysname     NULL
    )

    INSERT INTO @AllData( ID, FName, LName, MName )
                SELECT 1,'Fname1','Lname1','MName1'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2,'Fname2','Lname2',NULL
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3,'Fname3','Lname3','Mname3'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 4,'Fname4','Lname4',NULL

    INSERT INTO @ExcludeData( ID, FName, LName, MName )
                SELECT 1,'Fname1','Lname1','MName1'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2,'Fname2','Lname2',NULL

    SELECT a.ID,a.FName,a.LName,a.MName
    FROM @AllData a
    LEFT JOIN @ExcludeData b
    ON 
        ((a.ID=b.ID) OR (a.id IS NULL AND b.id IS NULL))
        AND
        ((a.FName=b.FName) OR (a.FName IS NULL AND b.FName IS NULL))
        AND
        ((a.LName=b.LName) OR (a.LName IS NULL AND b.LName IS NULL))
        AND
        ((a.MName=b.MName) OR (a.MName IS NULL AND b.MName IS NULL))
    WHERE 
        (b.ID IS NULL AND b.FName IS NULL AND b.LName IS NULL AND b.MName IS NULL)
```

Comment: Taking the example you gave. Say there was a record in the exclude table that was [5, 'Fname3', 'Lnname3', 'ALL']. Assuming that 'All' means that they want to eliminate all the Fname3 and Lname3 combinations regardless of Mname. How could you account for that while still letting other rows filter by the middle name column if they wish?